# Scatter plot of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format. I am trying to plot this data based on ClusterAssigned, with probably different colors for 0 and 1.

```
    Distance    ClusterAssigned
    23      1
    35      1
    20      1
    264     0
    830     0
```

I tried with this code but does not seem to yield perfect results.

```
groups = dfprintscatter.groupby('ClusterAssigned')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05) 
for name, group in groups:
        ax.plot(group.Distance, group.ClusterAssigned, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=5, label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: what do you consider perfect results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `scatter` function in matplotlib and there is no need to loop or do any grouping.

```
x = np.arange(len(dfprintscatter))
y = dfprintscatter.Distance
c = dfprintscatter.ClusterAssigned
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, marker='o')
```

Using seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot(x=np.arange(len(dfprintscatter)), y='Distance', hue='ClusterAssigned', fit_reg=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was actually looking for. Can I assign labels in plt.scatter?

Comment: You would have to loop to get the labels correct. It would be much easier to use seaborn.

Comment: I tried with seaborn, i get the error " regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hue'"

Comment: @user3447653 My fault. Regplot has no hue parameter. Try the same with 'lmplot'