# Appropriate handling of Pandas dataframe scatterplot with varying colors and marker sizes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, scatter

Given a dataframe df with columns A, B, C, and D,

```
     A    B      C     D
0    88  38  15.66  30.0
1    88  34  15.66  40.0
2    15  15  12.00  20.0
3    15  19   8.00  15.0
4    45  12   6.00  15.0
5    45  30   4.00  30.0
6    29  31   3.60  15.0
7    88  20   3.60  10.0
8    64  25   3.60  15.0
9    45  43   3.60  20.0
```

I want to make a scatter plot that graphs A vs B, with sizes based on C and colors based on D. After trying many ways to do this, I settled on grouping the data by D, then plotting each group in D:

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots()
factor=df.groupby('D')
for name, group in factor:
    axes.scatter(group.A,group.B,s=(group.C)**2,c=group.D,
     cmap='viridis',norm=Normalize(vmin=min(df.D),vmax=max(df.D)),label=name)
```

This yields the appropriate result, but the default legend() function is wrong. The groups listed in the legend have correct names, but incorrect colors and sizes (colors should vary by group, and sizes of all markers should be the same).

[image]

I tried to manually set the legend, which I can approximate the colors but can't get the sizes to be equal. Eventually I'd like a second legend that will link sizes to the appropriate levels of C.

```
axes.legend(loc=1,scatterpoints=1,fontsize='small',frameon=False,ncol=2)
leg=axes.get_legend()
for i in range(len(factor)):
    z=plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0,1,len(factor)))
    leg.legendHandles[i].set_color(z[i])
```

[image]

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what your data look like - it would be helpful if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The graphs you've posted don't seem to align with your example data.  The x- and y-axes both have values much higher than your `A` and `B` fields.  See my updated answer, using your example data as `df`.

Comment: Thanks; the data are derived from one twentieth of the total matrix that was used to generate the figures. I was trying to find a method that avoided seaborn, because attempts to modify the default seaborn styles fail in my jupyter interface.

Comment: What are the default seaborn styles you're having trouble modifying? It's mostly just Matplotlib under the hood, and most Seaborn functions have `kwargs` that can be passed to the underlying Matplotlib methods.  Consider updating your question with these restrictions and any errors you've been encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that seems to satisfy your requirements, using Seaborn's [`lmplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html). (Inspiration taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271046/scatter-plot-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe).)

First, generate some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10
min_size = 50
max_size = 300
A = np.random.random(n)
B = np.random.random(n)*2
C = np.random.randint(min_size, max_size, size=n)
D = np.random.choice(['Group1','Group2'], n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B,'C':C,'D':D})
```

Now plot:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lmplot(x='A', y='B', hue='D', 
           fit_reg=False, data=df, 
           scatter_kws={'s':df.C})
```

[image: sized, grouped scatter plot]

**UPDATE**
Given updated example data from OP, the same `lmplot()` approach should fulfill specifications: group legend is tracked by color, size of legend indicators is equal.

```
sns.lmplot(x='A', y='B', hue='D', data=df, 
           scatter_kws={'s':df.C**2}, fit_reg=False,)
```

[image: scatter2]